# What are the best practices working with postgres replication slot for big data processing?

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, replication, database-replication, debezium

I am using kafka source connector which captures data from postgres and creates topics. I have tested it with thousands of records. But i want to know if the replication slot work same with even 10 million records. Do i need to take any additional precautions?

Comment: i don't understand: how can a replication *slot* fail? It is just a simple data structure on the primary server.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz Albe, actually i am new to concept replication slot. I tried to explore about it. As per my knowledge, it keeps track of records being captured for replication / CDC. Can you please tell me how does it deal with data to keep track. What are the best practices to work with replication slots in production

Answer (score 0):

So in versions 9.3 and prior there used to be a problem in cases such as mentioned below:

keeping it simple with 1 master and 1 replica, if for some reason the replica is down for a very long time in a stopped state and doesn't come up;
and if the primary's WAL segments required by the standby server have already been recycled, the standby cannot catch up with the primary server, to solve this problem we used to have something called wal_keep_segments. Set a larger value and it kind of bandaids the problem.

moving to the newer versions of postgres 9.4 and further, we got the  `replication slot`.

So coming from official docs:

Replication slots provide an automated way to ensure that the master **does not remove WAL segments until they have been received by all standbys**, and that the master does not remove rows which could cause a recovery conflict even when the standby is disconnected.

So basically replication slots retain only the number of segments known to be needed. So basically it will function the way its designed to as mentioned above irrespective of the number of rows.

Hope this answers your question, see official docs for more [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION-SLOTS).